Are the lights of a city a problem for biyah?
If a couple is staying in a city like Manhattan, and the curtains of the hotel room are not enough to completely block the light from the city, is biyah forbidden? Or are there still things you can do to make it permissible?

This question might not be appropriate for this site, but fear not, it's not very hard to look up

The MB in 240:39 says that if it isn’t shining directly on you then it’s permitted. וה"ה לאור הלבנה ג"כ אסור ודוקא אם אור הלבנה מאיר עליהם להדיא אבל אם אינה מאירה עליהם אע"פ שמאירה לבית מותר

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
